# Session not being passed first time on log in

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

I have a basic log in set up for users to access a document request form. 
It works fine, except the first time I log in.  The first time, I get redirected to the correct page with the $_GET vars clearly showing the login was a success, but the Session has been killed/regenerated somehow, so it includes the login form instead of the account page. It only happens the first time I log in after opening a browser.

This has been giving me a headache for days.  I have session_start(); on top before everything, nothing is being sent before headers, so I don't get it.  Below is the code.

**partner_login.php**

```
       <?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['logtoken']=sha1(microtime('get_as_float'));
    $_SESSION['reqtoken']=sha1(microtime('get_as_float'));

    //I set some text vars here

    if(isset($_SESSION['loginsuccess'])&&($_SESSION['loginsuccess']=="1")){
    include_once('sqlconnect.php');
    $thisuser=$_SESSION['username'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$thisuser'";
    $result=$mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $firstname=$row['firstname'];
    $lastname=$row['lastname'];
}

$thiscontent=(isset($_SESSION['loginsuccess'])&&$_SESSION['loginsuccess']=="1")?include('account.php'):include('loginform.php');



$insideCONTENTHOLDER="
<div id='CONTENT' style='width:741px;min-height:800px;background-color:white;float:right;border-right:4px solid #a0a0a0;border-top:4px solid #a0a0a0;padding:20px;'>
".$txt['TITLE']."<p>".$txt['TEXT']."<p>".$thiscontent."</div><!--END CONTENT DIV-->";

include_once('template.php'); 

?>
```

**logingate.php**

```
<?php session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['logtoken'])||!isset($_POST['token'])||(empty($_SESSION['logtoken']))||(empty($_POST['token']))||($_SESSION['logtoken'] != $_POST['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['loginsuccess'] = "0";
    header( "Location: partner_login.php?loginfail=1&err=6" );//err 6 == session token!=post token
                                    }
elseif (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['password'])) {
    header( "Location: partner_login.php?loginfail=1&err=0" );//err 0 == one of them was not set
                                    }
elseif (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    header( "Location: partner_login.php?loginfail=1&err=00" );//err 00 == one of them was empty
                                    }
else{

    //connect to database $db, char set UTF_8
    include_once('sqlconnect.php');

    //sql injection protect
    function clean($thisvar){
        $thisvar=$mysqli->real_escape_string($thisvar);
        return $thisvar;
                }

    //escape all input
    $user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $pass = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    //salt and hash password from table
    $query="SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$user'";
    $result1=$mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result1->fetch_assoc();
    $passhash = sha1($pass.$row['salt']);

    //check that at least one row was returned
    $query2="SELECT * FROM userinfo WHERE username='$user' and passwordhash='$passhash'";
    $result=$mysqli->query($query2);

    $rowCheck = $result->num_rows;
    if($rowCheck > 0){

        //session variables
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['loginsuccess'] = "1";

        header( "Location: partner_login.php?lsuccess=1&user=$user" );

             }


      else {
         header( "Location: partner_login.php?loginfail=1&err=9" ); //err 9 == username and password don't match in table
          }
}
?>
```

Here is the phpinfo() section on sessions:

> Session Support   enabled Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
>   Registered serializer handlers    php php_binary wddx
>          Directive  Local Value Master Value  session.auto_start    Off Off     session.bug_compat_42   On  On  session.bug_compat_warn On  On
>   session.cache_expire  180 180  session.cache_limiter  nocache nocache
>   session.cookie_domain no value    no value
>   session.cookie_httponly   Off Off  session.cookie_lifetime    0   0
>   session.cookie_path   /   /  session.cookie_secure    Off Off
>   session.entropy_file  no value    no value  session.entropy_length    0   0
>   session.gc_divisor    100 100  session.gc_maxlifetime 1440    1440
>   session.gc_probability    1   1  session.hash_bits_per_character  4   4
>   session.hash_function 0   0  session.name PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
>   session.referer_check no value    no value
>   session.save_handler  files   files  session.save_path    /tmp    /tmp
>   session.serialize_handler php php  session.use_cookies    On  On
>   session.use_only_cookies  Off Off  session.use_trans_sid  0   0

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue once and it comes down that Sessions don't get passed from "www" to without the "www". So to combat this issue redirect all users to your site with www. or without the www before loading the rest of the page.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that is the problem.  I removed the site from the headers when posting here, but the actual code looks like:
`header( "Location: http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/partner_login.php?lsuccess=1&user=$user" );`

Comment: Try going to http://www.mysite.com/subfolder/partner_login.php and logging in then try going to http://mysite.com/subfolder/partner_login.php and login and see if one works but not the other. If so then this is your issue

Comment: Oh brother, I'm sorry I doubted you.   I could kiss you right now!  That was it!  I was always going to mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com

Comment: Using `header("Location: example.php");` solved my issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

Using below code to your fist appearing page like index.php on first line

```
session_start();
```